# Word meaning "kicking softly" or "brushing with the feet"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> I walked to the wall window, [...] the sawdust on the floor.

I could write *brushing the sawdust with my feet* but I want a shorter alternative, say a single word.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*[Scuffing](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scuff)* is a good choice here. It means to shuffle or scrape your feet along the ground (Dictionary.com reference). It would indicate reluctance or even some petulance depending on the context, like how a child might shuffle off after being to[ld to go to bed.

*[Scuffling](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scuffle)* is a similar word and possibly less harsh sounding (another Dictionary.com reference). I think shuffle is too light for what you want, and if scuff is too heavy, then this is about halfway between a scuff and a shuffle.

Comment: _scuff_ seems a bit harsh and I don't think you could leave a _scuff mark_ on sawdust, but in saying that I don't have an alternative in mind.

Comment: I do :) I agree on the scuffing. Scuffling is something old people do

Comment: I think _shuffling_ works, too, with the right preposition: _I walked to the wall window, shuffling through the sawdust on the floor_.

Answer (score 6):

"Dusturbing" the sawdust on the floor.

Comment: Heh. A spiritual +1.

Answer (score 4):

> I walked to the wall window, ***rustling*** the sawdust on the floor.

Typically used when walking through fallen leaves, I think it sets the right tone if there is a large amount of saw dust. Synonyms in this vein include: *stirring, disturbing, raking, swirling, fluttering.*

If you want to convey a light covering of sawdust, you could use a term that describes your feet more than the sawdust, such as:

> I walked to the wall window, ***tracking through*** the sawdust on the floor.

Used in the meaning of

> **1 a :**  detectable evidence (as the wake of a ship, a line of footprints, or a wheel rut) that something has passed
>       **b :**  a path made by or as if by repeated footfalls :  trail

<sub>[Merriam-Webster, *track*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/track)</sub>

Synonyms for this flavor: *imprinting, furrowing, gouging, drifting* (as in snow drifts), *etching.*

Answer (score 2):

> I walked to the wall window, *toeing* the sawdust on the floor.

Note that *toeing* is a sexual term according to UrbanDictionary, but I suspect that definition is something some prankster made up rather than an actual practice.

Comment: ...aren't most things sexual according to UrbanDictionary?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [Waft](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Waft):

> I walked to the wall window, *wafting* through the sawdust on the floor.

[TheFreeDictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Waft)

> **1.** To cause to go gently and smoothly through the air or over water.
>   **2.** To convey or send floating through the air or over water.
>
> ....
>
> **2.** the act or an instance of wafting
>   **4.** a wafting motion

Comment: When I think of "wafting", I picture something airborne, like scent or dust.

Comment: Yes, which is what wafting also means - I thought it was perfect since you can waft and then whatever you waft through also wafts

Comment: Wafting through the waftiness of the wafting dust! :-)

Comment: This sounds simply incorrect to me; it strikes me as the sort of thing someone might write after five minutes with a thesaurus, without actually knowing what "wafting" means. Walking is extremely unlike wafting, even if you're graceful and light-footed.

Comment: If I walk through sawdust, I am sure the dust would start wafting. I think it is very poetic :) So _I approached the wall window, wafting through the sawdust on the floor._

Answer (score 1):

I walked to the wall window, *padding* across the sawdust on the floor.

I *padded* to the window through the sawdust on the floor.

[dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pad?s=t)

> verb (used without object), padded, padding.
>       7. to travel on foot; walk.
>       8. to walk so that one's footsteps make a dull, muffled sound.

[websters 1913](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=Pad&resource=Webster%27s&quicksearch=on)

> Pad, v. i.
>       1. To travel heavily or slowly. Bunyan.

Answer (score 1):

> I walked to the wall window, **treading** the sawdust on the floor.

This is but a suggestion of the many that are available.

I feel the answer to your question lies both in the distinction of the action and its effect. The action could; pad or stomp. The result could; grace or displace.

*p.s.(I am new to this exchange and apologise in advance if my thoughts on this are not in the appropriate format - still learning.)*